# Using find, execute command and output to new file with original filename and appended extension

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have a bunch of files that I want to find with `find`. Then I want to run a command (which outputs to `STDOUT`) and write this to a new file with an appended extension. This is what I have so far:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec command -O -I{} > {}.nav \;
```

So say that `find` gives me the file list:

```
./1/file1.txt
./2/file2.txt
```

I would like to have the result:

```
./1/file1.txt
./1/file1.txt.nav
./2/file2.txt
./2/file2.txt.nav
```

But I'm only getting one new file which all content has been concatenate to called `{}.nav`. Any tips on how I should proceed?

Comment: @andand : Are you aware, that the way you wrote it, the options `-O -I{} `  are passed to _command_? Also, `{}.nav` is an odd name for a file, but of course you can name your files as you want....

Comment: Agree that `-O -I{}` are being passed to `command` which doesn't seem like what you need. ALSO can you give us a command to use for our testing, Could we just use `echo` or `cat` instead? Good luck.

Comment: @andad : One thing to try would be to make a script that does what ever you need to make your `.nav` file. I think the `>` redirection is only being processed once by the shell. If you can move that redirection into a script that gets executed for each file, you should be good. Good luck.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, I know `-O -I{}` aare passed to command. I thought `find` 
 would substitute the `{}` in `{}.nav` with the filename being processed. Thank you @shellter, I thought that `>` would write to `<filename>.nav` (i.e. for each file found from `find`. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @andand : This is correct. Hence, `command` should indeed get the respective arguments. But what is then this mysterious _command_? I guess you did not literally write the word `command` after the `-exec`, but the actual name of the command you want to execute here.

Comment: The "real" command is just a program that dumps coordinates to `STDOUT`. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

you can try the below, using `tee` command

```
 for file in $(find . -name "*.txt"); do <command> "$file" | tee "$file".nav; done
```

from `man tee`

> tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files

Comment: Thanks nullPointer. So there is no way to do all this directly with find without involving a for-loop and tee?

Comment: Thanks @nullPointer, this is the closest to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to acheive the desired result without using a for loop by using `bash` and `tee`. Since `find` outputs the results to stdout for each file found, you are still going to need to use `tee`. For example if you wanted to grep all lines with the value "HelloWorld" for each file and output the results into a separate file you can run the command below:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec bash -c 'grep "HelloWorld" {} | tee "{}.nav"' \;
```

As you can see the command above does not require a for loop but still produces the desired result. Please accept this as the answer as it directly answers your question but also omits the for loop in @nullPointer's answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `awk` with `find` as follows, if I understood your requirement correctly.

```
find -type f -name "*.txt" | awk '{print $0 ORS $0".nav"}'
```

Comment: Thanks you @RavinderSingh13. It seems like it only outputs to `STDOUT` and not writing to file.

Comment: @andand, Sure, your could append ` > out_file` to my code and it should write into a file then, cheers.